# Using Google OR tools for crew scheduling

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm searching for a proper way to use Google OR tools for solving an annual ship crew scheduling problem. I tried to follow the scheduling problem examples provided, but I couldn't find a way to set a 4 dimensional decision variable needed ( `D[i,j,k,t]` , `i` for captains, `j` for engineers, `k` for ship and `t` for time-period (days or weeks)).

Although there are many examples given (for C#) the major problems I faced is the way to set and utilize this main decision variable, and how to use the Decision Builder, since in all examples the variables had 2 dimensions, and were .flattened in order to make the comparisons. Unfortunately, I  haven't found a way to use smaller D-Variables, since the penalty score (minimize penalty problem) is estimated by possible sets of Captains-Engineers , Captains-Ships, and Engineer Ships.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create you 4D array, and then fill it with variables one by one.

Here is the code for matrices:

```
public IntVar[,] MakeIntVarMatrix(int rows, int cols, long min, long max) {
  IntVar[,] array = new IntVar[rows, cols];
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
      array[i,j] = MakeIntVar(min, max);
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

This being said, please use the CP-SAT solver as the original CP solver is deprecated.

For an introduction:

see:

- https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#cp-solver_example/
- https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/ortools/sat/doc

Comment: thanks, will try to modelize it like that, one more question though, i see that in every example in order to use the decision builder at the end of the problem we there always is a flattened decision variable, how can i face that on a 3d or 4d var ?

Comment: You need to flatten all variables to a single 1D array. My advice, each time you create a var, you append it to the 1D array. Still, I would drop the CP solver for the CP-SAT. With the CP-SAT, do not bother specifying search.

Comment: Thanks again for your help again, just have 2 final questions that bother me ( keep in mind my programming background is not the finest one ).  1) long min -long max on the array, did u name those like that for example or they should be called like that during the declaration of the 4d Dvar.   b) at which point in the code should i insert the varriables into the 1D array( I mean after i call the CpSolver solver = new CpSolver(); command ?-- should i do it with a 4x For (int i=0 etc..)  ----- thank you very much again though

Comment: These are the bounds of the variables you want to create. Look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/README.md#c-code-samples-1. You first create the model, add variables and constraints. Then create the solver and solve.